# maximization with decimal numbers

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a very simple question (I'm a beginner on mathematica, and didn't find the answer here).
When I try to maximize a simple function like
Maximize[x - 0.5*x^(4/3), x]
I obtain an error message "the function value... is not a real number".
 When I replace "0.5" by "1/2" I get the correct anwer. I also get an answer with any integer, but never with a decimal number.
Eg "2.5" doesnt work, but "5/2" works.
What is the problem please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict x to be positive it works as expected:

```
NMaximize[{x - 0.5*x^(4/3), x > 0}, x]
(* {0.84375, {x -> 3.375}} *)
```

Comment: Additionally, one might want to apply `Rationalize[]` to the exponent.

Comment: `Maximize[{x - 0.5*x^(4/3), FunctionDomain[x - 0.5*x^(4/3), x]}, x]`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

Maximize[x - c*x^(4/3), x] /. c -> .5

> {0.84375, {x -> 3.375}}

as a bit of explanation, when you give `Maximize` everything exact it uses analytic methods to find the value. As soon as you give it a float (inexact) value it switches to numerical methods which produce complex results for negative x.